# Get appsettings.json path from another project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, path, appsettings

I have an `appsettings.json` file that is being used by an ASP.NET Core application.

Another project in the same solution needs to use an `IConfiguration`, which is why I need to first build it, but to build it, I need to supply the path to the `appsettings.json` file it will be reading the configuration from.

There lies the problem - do I really have to hard-code the path to my `appsettings.json` file in the other project, or is there a more profound way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Why not put the data you need to another project's appsettings.json?Hard-code the path like `C:\xxx\xxx\appsettings.json`is not a good idea.Once you change the location,you need to change your code.

Comment: Because if I do that, I'll have repeatable configuration, i.e if I change the value in one config - I need to change it in the other as well. This is as bad as having a hard-coded path.